# PyDev paste to console with blank lines

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, indentation

I use PyDev in Eclipse to write Python code.  I make heavy use of the interactive shell--it's the main reason I use Python.  But I run into "unexpected indent" errors when I try to paste code with blank lines into the editor (either through the Ctrl-Alt-Enter keybinding or through direct cut and paste).  An example that breaks:

```
def test_function():
    x = 1 + 2
    y = x - 1

    if x > y:
        print('x > y')

    return(y)
```

This yields "IndentationError: unexpected indent," even though this code is totally legal based on PEP 8.  The reason for this, of course, is that the interactive shell auto-indents things, and it uses a blank line to signal the end of a code block.  Based on some searches, I think what I need is something like the magic %paste in IPython or the ability to turn auto-indentation off.

Is there a way to paste code blocks with blank lines in PyDev without causing indentation errors?  (Two possible workarounds are to comment the empty line or to use a '\' at the end of the previous line.  I'm looking for something that solves the problem directly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve this.  An empty line in the interactive shell has the special meaning of "Now start running this!"  It has nothing to do with any autoindenter.

You can put a `#` at the beginning of each empty line, then it is ignored:

```
def test_function():
  x = 1 + 2
  y = x - 1
#
  if x > y:
    print('x > y')
#
  return(y)
```

But that is ugly as hell, of course.

Comment: Thanks--I was hoping for better news, but after a lot of searching, I figured it might be impossible.  That's life without curly braces.